# python Queue not passing correct data

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

Just found the Queue module which is helping me adapt the pyftpdlib module. I'm running an very strict FTP server, and my goal is to restrict the filenames available to upload. This is to prevent people from uploading whatever they want (it's actually the backend of an upload client, not a complete FTP server).

I have this in the ftpserver Authorizer:

```
def fetch_worlds(queue, username):
    while queue.empty():
        worlds = models.World.objects.filter(is_synced=True, user__username=username)
        print worlds

        queue.put(worlds, timeout=1)

class FTPAuthorizer(ftpserver.DummyAuthorizer):

    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.t = None # Thread
        self.world_item = None

    def has_perm(self, username, perm, path=None):

        print "Checking permission\n"

        if perm not in ['r','w']:
            return False

        # Check world name        
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=fetch_worlds, args=(self.q, username))
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()

        self.world_item = self.q.get() 

        print "WORLDITEM: %s" % self.world_item

        if path is not None:
            path = os.path.basename(path)
            for world in self.world_item:
                test = "{0}_{1}.zip".format(username, world.name)
                if path == test:
                    print "Match on %s" % test
                    return True

        return False
```

My issue is, after the server starts, the first time I STOR a file, it does an initial db call and gets all the worlds properly. But when I then add another world (for example, set `is_synced=True` on one, it still returns the old data from `self.q.get()`. has_perm() is called every time a file is uploaded, and it needs to return live data (to check if a file is allowed).

For example, brand new server:

1. STOR file.zip, `self.q.get()` returns `<World1, World2>`
2. Update the database via other methods etc
3. STOR file2.zip, inside `fetch_worlds`, `print worlds` returns `<World1, World2, World3>` but `self.q.get()` returns `<World1, World2>`

Just found the Queue module and it seemed like it would be helpful but I can't get the implementation right.

(also couldn't add tag `pyftpdlib`)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what could be happening here:

1. when `has_perm` is called, you create a `Thread` that will query a database (?) to add elements to the queue
2. after calling `start` the call to the database will take some time
3. meanwhile in your main thread you entered `q.get` which will block.
4. the db call finishes and the result is added to the queue
5. and is immediately removed from the queue again by the blocking `q.get`
6. the queue is now empty, your thread enters the while-loop again and executes the same query again and puts the result onto the queue.
7. the next call to `q.get` will return that instead of what it expects.

you see, you could have a race condition here, that already is aparent from the fact that you're adding something to a queue in a loop while you don't have a loop when pulling.
also you assume the element you get from the queue is the result to what you have put onto it before. that doesn't have to be true. 
 if you call `has_perm` two times this will result in two calls to `fetch_worlds` with the possibility that the `queue.empty()` check for one of the calls fails. so only one result will be put onto the queue. now you have two threads waiting on `q.get`, but only one will get a result, while the oter one waits until one becomes ready...

`has_perm` looks like it should be a blocking call anyway.

Comment: The Threading was only an attempt to get it to (somehow) get fresh results. If I take out all the Threading and Queues, and just have the db query before `if path is not None`, it still doesn't get fresh results. I have to restart the server for the query to fetch anything new. Probably my misunderstanding of how all this works, though I'm hoping what I want is still achievable.